# Is there a way to make div overflow symmetrical?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write text in a thin div so that the letters are centered in the div but overflow a bit on each side, like this:

[image: what i want]

But the overflow makes it so that they only extend on one side, like this:

[image: what i got]

Does anyone know how to customize the overflow so this doesn't happen (or alternately, a better what to do this in general)? I'd like to avoid making another div that contains this one if possible.

EDIT: Sorry, should have put the code in. Here's the HTML:

```
        <div class="bracket bracket-body" style="margin-left: 56.75%; margin-top: 20vh; height: 100vh;">
            Text
</div>
```

Here's the associated CSS:

```
.bracket {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.bracket-body {
width: 1.5vh;
writing-mode: tb;
text-direction: mixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to bracket body:

```css
.bracket-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a pseudo-element

```css
h3 {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

h3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h3>TEXT</h3>
```